# Which View engines in ASP.NET MVC have the most support, documentation, and roadmap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I do not want to spend a lot of time on something that does not have lot of support or no roadmap. Do we even have to worry about this view engines in the wake of vs2010/.Net 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, just use what you want that works today

Both Spark and NHaml are complete enough for production use

What special requirements do you have?

**Spark** markup is more like *pure* HTML

**NHaml** is just fun and geeky and quick

Comment: I wouldn't say that Spark *gives* more pure HTML. All the view engines can produce the same HTML. I *would*, however, say that Spark's syntax in itself looks more like HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to the WebForms view engine and you should be fine. It's developed by Microsoft, it has decent documentation, it's the default view engine and it's partially tied to the WebForms framework which isn't going anywhere (at least not yet).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to worry about view engines at all ... you can always use the Microsoft view engine with no further consideration.  IMHO, the only other view engine that is worthwhile for a large/production project is Spark.  Regarding long-term support ... who knows.  It's open source, and the creator has moved on to Microsoft.  This could either be a good thing (i.e. possibly Spark features in future MS releases), neutral (no change), or bad (if he has little time to improve Spark due to time commitment.

Comment: Can't speak for Spark. but NHaml owner is working for Microsoft too. NHaml is still being maintained